How change columns color in chart under mathematical conditions Excel.Xlwing (by code, not FC in excel)s?
Is possible to change the color of a column under mathematical conditions in Excel-Xlwings, by code (not FC in excel). I mean, with the table:



Name
vote




Rossi
5


Bianchi
7


Verdi
8


Neri
4



I would like to build a chart with the vote under 6 (if vote<6) , Rossi and Neri, in RED color, the others in GREEN.
Thank you.

Sounds like a Conditional Formatting candidate. You can individually colour a cell based on its value just by checking the value and setting the Fill depending if it's above or below 6. However  the colour will be static and specific to the cell at the time the script is run. If you use CF then the colour can be set based on the value of the cell across the range (e.g. B2 - B5) and change if the value moves above or below 6.

You would be making the CF addition to the Excel file using Code incorporating Xlwings (or could do with Openpyxl ).

The following is code that implements Conditional Formatting on data in the range B2:B5 using Xlwings.
The code also creates the workbook and writes the sample data.
import xlwings as xw
from xlwings import constants
import pandas as pd
from xlwings.utils import rgb_to_int


with xw.App(visible=True) as xl:
    # Create a sample DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        'Name': ['Rossi', 'Bianchi', 'Verdi', 'Neri'],
        'Vote': [5, 7, 8, 4]
    })

    wb = xw.Book()
    ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

    ws.range('A1').options(index=False).value = df
    ws.range("A1:B1").Bold = True

    ### Cells to include in the Conditional Formatting range
    cf_range = ws.range('B2:B5')

    ### Create CF Rule for values less than 6 Fill Red
    cf1 = cf_range.api.FormatConditions.Add(
        Type=constants.FormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        Operator=constants.FormatConditionOperator.xlLess,
        Formula1=6
    )

    cf_range.api.FormatConditions(1).Interior.PatternColorIndex = constants.Constants.xlAutomatic
    cf_range.api.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = rgb_to_int((255, 0, 0))
    cf_range.api.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False


    ### Create CF Rule for values greater and equal to 6 Fill Green
    cf2 = cf_range.api.FormatConditions.Add(
        Type=constants.FormatConditionType.xlCellValue,
        Operator=constants.FormatConditionOperator.xlGreaterEqual,
        Formula1=6
    )

    ws.range('B2:B5').api.FormatConditions(2).Interior.PatternColorIndex = constants.Constants.xlAutomatic
    ws.range('B2:B5').api.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = rgb_to_int((0, 255, 0))
    ws.range('B2:B5').api.FormatConditions(2).StopIfTrue = False


    wb.save('cf_example.xlsx')

Example Sheet;
Note, this is not an Excel Table just tabulated data 

